# Algorithm for Cutting Patterns

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Let's say I have a given length `c` and I need to cut out several pieces of different lengths `a{i}`, where `i` is the index of a specific piece. The length of every piece is smaller or equal to the length `c`. I need to find all possible permutations of cutting patterns.

Does someone has a smart approach for such tasks or an algorithm to solve this?

The function could look something similar to this:

```
Pattern[] getPatternList(double.. a, double c);
```

The input is hence a list of different sizes and the total available space. My goal is to optimize/minimize the trim loss. 
I'll use the simplex algorithm for that but to create an linear programming model, I need a smart way to determine all the cutting patterns.

Comment: Please add input and output examples

Comment: You really need all of them? Typically only cutting patterns that "help" given the current reduced prices are necessary (if you're doing Cutting Stock with column generation). You'd only need one at the time and you can use the usual Knapsack tricks.

Comment: @harold: All relevant ones. Since it's hard to determine the quality of a pattern, I would prefer to have too much instead of missing a good one.

Comment: @Ohad: I updated my question according to your requirement.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to do. Using simplex, but needing all the cutting-patterns for that? What do you want to do? What is a cutting-pattern for you? If it's a subset of selected items, it's just space - sum(subset) to determine the trim-loss (no simplex needed). Why not just use integer-programming to select this subset while minimizing trim-loss (you would not need to think about these cuts before).

Comment: @BastianSchoettle I added the integer-programming approach to my answer.

Comment: @sascha: Let's say I have 3 different pieces {a,b,c}, where a=5cm, b=3cm and c=2cm. One piece of resources material is 10cm. One cutting pattern would hence be 1 a, 1 b and 1c. And another could be 2b and 1c. So, I would than for example need at least 10 pieces of a and 4 of c. To minimize usage of resources material under given constraints, I would of course use an linear integer programming approach. But do you know another way to model it as such without the patterns?

Comment: @BastianSchoettle (1) Your question did not say, that items can be picked multiple times. You should have been more clear about that (2) Reading your comment above, the problem you want to solve is nowhere near that, which you describe. You **now** describe somewhat the cutting-stock problem in one dimension. So just read up on that. It's common to use column-generation, but this concept is a bit different to *generate all possible patterns before*.

Comment: @sascha: Yes, you are right about your advice. I will keep it in my mind for the future. Thank you very much for your answer and the code. I'll have a look at the column-generator and try that approach. It seemed also to me a bit inefficient to determine the cutting patterns upfront but this approach was somehow intuitive:) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There are exponentially many cutting-patterns in general. So it might not be feasible to construct them all (time and memory)
- If you need to optimize some cutting based on some objective, enumerating all possible cuttings is a bad approach (like @harold mentioned)

  - A bad analogy (which does not exactly apply here as your base-problem is np-hard):
  - solving 2-SAT is possible in polynomial-time
  - enumerating all 2-SAT solutions is *Sharp-P-complete* (an efficient algorithm would imply P=NP, so there might be none!)
- A simple approach (to generate all valid cutting-patterns):

  - Generate all permutations if items = ordering of items (bounded by !n)
  - Place them one after another and stop if c is exceeded
  - (It would be a good idea to do this incrementally; build one permutation after another)
  - **Assumption**: each item can only be selected *once*
  - **Assumption**: moving/shifting a cut within a free range does not generate a new solution. It it would: solution-space is possibly an uncountably infinite set

**edit**

#### Code

Here is a more powerful approach handling the problem with the same assumptions as described above. It uses integer-programming to minimize the trim-loss, implemented in python with the use of cvxpy (and a commercial-solver; can be replaced by an open-source solver like cbc):

```
import numpy as np
from cvxpy import *
np.random.seed(1)

# random problem
SPACE = 25000
N_ITEMS = 10000
items = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=N_ITEMS)

def minimize_loss(items, space):
    N = items.shape[0]
    X = Bool(N)
    constraint = [sum_entries(mul_elemwise(items, X)) <= space]
    objective = Minimize(space - sum_entries(mul_elemwise(items, X)))
    problem = Problem(objective, constraint)
    problem.solve(solver=GUROBI, verbose=True)

    print('trim-loss: ', problem.value)
    print('validated trim-loss: ', space - sum(np.dot(X.value.flatten(), items)))
    print('# selected items: ', np.count_nonzero(np.round(X.value)))

print('items: ', items)
print('space: ', SPACE)
minimize_loss(items, SPACE)
```

#### Output

```
items:  [5 8 9 ..., 5 3 5]
space:  25000
Parameter OutputFlag unchanged
   Value: 1  Min: 0  Max: 1  Default: 1
Changed value of parameter QCPDual to 1
   Prev: 0  Min: 0  Max: 1  Default: 0
Optimize a model with 1 rows, 10000 columns and 8987 nonzeros
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range    [1e+00, 9e+00]
  Objective range [1e+00, 9e+00]
  Bounds range    [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range       [2e+04, 2e+04]
Found heuristic solution: objective -25000
Presolve removed 1 rows and 10000 columns
Presolve time: 0.01s
Presolve: All rows and columns removed

Explored 0 nodes (0 simplex iterations) in 0.01 seconds
Thread count was 1 (of 4 available processors)

Optimal solution found (tolerance 1.00e-04)
Best objective -2.500000000000e+04, best bound -2.500000000000e+04, gap 0.0%
trim-loss:  0.0
validated trim-loss:  [[ 0.]]
# selected items:  6516
```

**edit v2**
After read your new comments, it is clear, that your model-description was incomplete/imprecise and nothing above tackles the problem you want to solve. It's a bit sad.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enumerate all permutations of `a`, and then take the longest prefix that has length less than or equal to `c`.

This sounds like a version of the knapsack problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), and nobody knows an efficient way to do this.

Comment: There's actually a much more specific name for the problem, although it's a variant of (and reducible to) the knapsack problem: [Stock Cutting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem)

Comment: @jedwards: Thanks.